# Conditional JOIN with two different keys

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that produces two separate IDs:

```
SELECT
date, 
user_id,
vendor_id,
SUM(purchase) user_purchase
SUM(spend) vendor_spend
GROUP BY 1,2,3
FROM tabla.abc
```

This produces results like this:

```
date   user_id   vendor_id   user_purchase   vendor_spend
1/1/18   123      NULL         5.00             0.00   
1/1/18   NULL     456          0.00             10.00
```

I want to join it on a table that looks like this:

```
client_id   user_id   vendor_id
456789      123       NULL
101112      NULL      456
```

But the problem is, I obviously want to join it on both the appropiate IDs so my final output can look like this:

```
date    client_id  user_id   vendor_id   user_purchase   vendor_spend
1/1/18   456790     123      NULL         5.00             0.00   
1/1/18   101112     NULL     456          0.00             10.00
```

So is there a way I can do like, a conditional join? Something like `WHERE user_id IS NULL THEN...` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`not distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) because one of the argument may be null:

```
select *
from (
    select
        date, 
        user_id,
        vendor_id,
        sum(purchase) user_purchase,
        sum(spend) vendor_spend
    from table1
    group by 1,2,3
    ) t1
join table2 t2 
    on (t1.user_id, t1.vendor_id) 
    is not distinct from (t2.user_id, t2.vendor_id)
```

Note that for performance reasons you should join already aggregated table (hence I have placed the original query in a derived table).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
date, 
COALESCE(lu.client_id, lv.client_id) AS client_id,
user_id,
vendor_id,
SUM(purchase) user_purchase
SUM(spend) vendor_spend
FROM tabla.abc
LEFT JOIN tabla.link AS lu USING (user_id)
LEFT JOIN tabla.link AS lv USING (vendor_id)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the sufficient join is just this:

```
FROM aggregated_table t1
LEFT JOIN client_id_table t2
ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
OR t1.vendor_id=t2.vendor_id
```

because as I understand you need to join by user id if there is user id and by vendor id if there is vendor id. Using a left join with OR does exactly that.

Also, conditional join is possible as well. If you're familiar with a `CASE` statement it works perfectly well in join conditions. Similar thing can be expressed as:

```
FROM aggregated_table t1
LEFT JOIN client_id_table t2
ON CASE 
    WHEN t1.user_id is not null THEN t1.user_id=t2.user_id
    WHEN t1.vendor_id is not null THEN t1.vendor_id=t2.vendor_id
END
```

but this is too verbose compared to the previous option that I think should produce the same result